# how to test onChange write a test for a functional component jest + react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I can't write a test for this line, it says that it is not covered, how can I write a test for this line?

```
  onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setTestData(value)}
```

file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
    
    const Test = () => {
      const [testdata, setTestData] = useState<any>("");
    
      const [, setTestData2] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
      return (
        <OutlinedInput
          placeholder="Test"
          value={testdata}
          onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setTestData(value)}
        />
      );
    };
    
    export default Test;
```

jest

```
import React from "react";

import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

import Test from ".";

describe("Test", () => {
  test("test1", () => {
    const { container } = render(<Test />);

    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: How would you expect a user's actions to invoke that handler? Right now you're not doing _anything_ but render the component in the test, so have no reason to expect it to be covered.

Comment: Select the input, type something in it and check the value changed. But ask yourself if you really need to test this.

Comment: tests are needed for this code, just deleted unnecessary data. How to write tests for it?

Comment: Yes, you need to cover it, because the compiler writes that this line is not covered. Can't write a test for it

Comment: I run it via npm test -- --coverage says this line is not covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fireEvent` to trigger the change event on the input box.

Select the input box and then fire the event like below :

```
 const input = screen.getByRole('input', {name : ''}); // this is sample one , you need to add the role and name value based on what you have.

 fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'a'}})
```

Then you can validate if state is updated or not.

Read more about `fireEvent`  [**here.**](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/)